# Show multiple list of group member in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 table like this:
Table State
id_state state

```
1        AAA
2        BBB
```

Table Province
id_province id_state province

```
1           1    qqq
2           1    www
3           2    eee
4           2    yyy
5           2    zzz
```

I want to show that a state have a few province in select-option HTML form like this:

```
AAA     qqq
        www
BBB     eee
        yyy
        zzz
```

Or in HTML code:

```
<select name='AAA'>
    <option value='qqq'>qqq</option>
    <option value='www'>www</option>
</select>
<select name='BBB'>
    <option value='eee'>eee</option>
    <option value='yyy'>yyy</option>
    <option value='zzz'>zzz</option>

</select>
```

I want to do it because if value in the database has changed, so the select-option also change. I use codeigniter framework.

So far I have try this in model:

```
SELECT * FROM state s,province p WHERE s.id_state=p.id_state
```

But the result become:

```
AAA     qqq
AAA     www
BBB     eee
BBB     yyy
BBB     zzz
```

If I use GROUP BY it will only return AAA and BBB.
Thanks

Comment: Using `GROUP_CONCAT()` you can get a comma delimited list of the province.

Comment: How to use GROUP_CONCAT() to implement select option list? Can you explain in detail? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
  s.state,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.province) AS province 
FROM state s
  LEFT JOIN province p ON s.id_state = p.id_state
GROUP BY s.id_state
```

By doing this you will get something like this:

```
AAA     qqq,www
BBB     eee,yyy,zzz
```

Then you can loop over each row of query result and for each row loop over the comma delimited list of province.

> Edit : If you want to get the results as html code for `province`. This will avoid the looping over the list.

```
SELECT 
  s.state,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<option>',p.province,'<\/option>') SEPARATOR ' ') AS provinceOption 
FROM state s
  LEFT JOIN province p ON s.id_state = p.id_state
GROUP BY s.id_state
```

By doing this you will get something like this:

```
AAA     <option>qqq</option><option>www</option>
BBB     <option>eee</option><option>yyy</option><option>zzz</option>
```

Then you can loop over each row of query result and simply output the `provinceOption`.

Comment: If you're going to loop (which you should) there's absolutely no point in using GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @Strawberry For creating the options you have to. Is there any better choice rather than returning the html code from query?

Comment: Just return a well-ordered array, and loop through that.

Comment: @Strawberry *well-ordered array* can you clarify? Look at the output. The options are not for same select.

Comment: a query with an order by clause can produce a 'well-ordered array', or it can be sorted in php (or even JavaScript)

Comment: @Beginner Then how to show the select option in HTML? I'm sorry, I still don't understand.

Comment: @Strawberry Can you reply an answer with detailed information? thanks

Comment: @SafiraAdiputri Simply `echo` the `proviceOption` for each state.

Comment: @Strawberry I looked about this and you have to loop over list for each state unless you are returning the options as html code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a php coder (that much should be obvious) - but this gets you the general idea:

```
<?php
require('path/to/mysqli/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT s.state
     , p.province
  FROM state s
  JOIN province p
    ON p.state_id = s.state_id
 ORDER
    BY state, province;
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$state = '';

echo "<table>\n";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($row['state']==$state){
  $state_out = '';
  } else {
  $state_out = $row['state'];
    $state = $row['state'];

}
echo "<tr>\n
       <td>$state_out</td>\n
       <td>{$row['province']}</td>\n
      </tr>\n
      ";
}

echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Comment: By showing `tr td` this can be done easily. Can you show this for `select`?

Comment: @Beginner Where is your previous answer? It work like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your below data in an array or if it is already in an array. Then please proceed with my below code.

```
AAA     qqq
AAA     www
BBB     eee
BBB     yyy
BBB     zzz
```

Please take your data in array as below and then you get the desired result.

```
    <?php
    $data = array(
        array('state' => 'AAA', 'province' => 'qqq'),
        array('state' => 'AAA', 'province' => 'www'),
        array('state' => 'BBB', 'province' => 'eee'),
        array('state' => 'BBB', 'province' => 'yyy'),
        array('state' => 'BBB', 'province' => 'zzz'),
    );

$prev_state = "";
$current_state = "";
$c = 0;
$max = sizeof($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    if ($data[$i]['state'] != $prev_state) {
        $current_state = $data[$i]['state'];
        ?>
        <select name="<?php echo $data[$i]['state']; ?>">
            <?php for ($j = 0; $i + $j < $max; $j++) {
                if ($data[$i + $j]['state'] == $current_state) {
                    ?>
                    <option value = "<?php echo $data[$i + $j]['province']; ?>"><?php echo $data[$i + $j]['province']; ?></option>
                <?php
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                $prev_state = $data[$i + $j]['state'];
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
    $prev_state = $data[$i]['state'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At controller's function write code like this

```
$this->db->from('Province p');
$this->db->select('p.province,s.state');
$this->db->join('State s','s.id_state = p.id_state','INNER');
$results=$this->db->get()->result();
$states=array();
foreach($results as $r)
{
    $states[$r->state][]=$r->province;
}
//now send this $states to your view;
//$this->load->view('your_view_file',array('states'=>$states));
```

Now at your view

```
<?php
foreach($states as $state=>$provinces)
{
    ?>
        <select name="<?php echo $state;?>">
            <?php
                foreach($provinces as $province)
                {
                    ?>
                    <option value='<?php echo $province;?>'><?php echo $province;?></option>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    <?php
}
?>
```

You can do it lots of way I just provide one.Hope this helps you.